# hydra returns all passwords tested as found

Tags: web-application, hydra

i have tried this command

```
hydra localhost http-form-get "/DVWA-master/vulnerabilities/brute/?username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=submit:F=incorrect:H=Cookie\:security=low; PHPSESSID=rch1oft4bbq68a3k656kla2geg" -l admin -P passwordlist.txt
```

i have installed dvwa project on my windows machine and i am testing this comandon my wsl debian on my windows

[image]

Comment: so there is no solution for this probleme except than bruteforcing the main login page or  desactivating it manualy and then u can brutforce the dvwa chalenge